# css centering does not work in Phonegap

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am trying to center an image with some text underneath. Works fine when I display in chrome. It also works well on an emulator using Opera Mobile. But when I create my phonegap app with the html/css files, the image refuses to center when run in Android.

Here is my css:

```
.centered {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could this be an issue with `position: fixed;`?

Try eg.

```
.centered {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.centered { 
width: 100%;
height: auto; 
position: fixed; 
top: 20%; 
text-align:center; 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend defining the width of your image and using

```
    .centered{
margin:0 auto;
}
```